# Segmentation fault when finding gcc version by command gcc --version

Tags: gcc

I wanna find gcc version on my mac. But after I typed the following command in the terminal:

gcc --version

the output says "Segmentation fault: 11", which is very weird. Is it because I typed the wrong command or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well. Homebrew's gcc46 was broken. I removed it

```
brew uninstall gcc46
```

and then symlinked gcc-4.2 back to the standard gcc command

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/gcc && sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 /usr/bin/gcc
```

If you need a newer version, uninstall gcc46 anyway and reinstall it / install 4.9 etc. It might have broken due to the update of ssl or libc (GHOST)and lost the link to those libraries.